# Textfield's text must appear little bit right

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

How can I get effect like this one?

[image]

For now I am using texts like @"  Password". So I just add two symbols. But I need clear text without spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `leftView` for your `textField`

```
  UIView *spacerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 0)];
  textField.leftView = spacerView;
  textField.leftViewMode=UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
  [textField setDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set 'leftView' property of your textfield

```
 textfield.leftView = [self paddingView];
 textfield.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Declare paddingView as

```
- (UIView*) paddingView
{
    return [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
}
```

here you can set padding by width property of this view